# Cloning a server Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, clone, scalr

I am using Scalr and need to clone a live farm.

I see the option to do this but I am apprehensive, can I clone my live running instance safely without interrupting it?

The documentation is a little sparse on whether the target farm is active or not or what the consequences might be or if there are any prerequisites.

Call me cynical but it seems to good to be true if I can just click "cone" then sit back and pat myself on the back.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely clone a live/production farm in Scalr. When you clone the farm, you are really just copying the farm's configuration (the roles, scaling settings, etc...), so the running instances are not affected.

Cloning is a great feature in Scalr that has saved me plenty of time, but be aware that you might have a little work to do on your clone once you've pressed the button. It depends on what your cloning, but as an example you may need to setup a new virtual host and domain, or restore some data to a database.